# popup message before deleting data

Tags: php, popup

I'm trying to put popup message in this code before user delete data. Here is my code.

```
while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $test['FailID'];

    echo "<tr align='center'>"; 
    echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['FailID']."</font></td>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>" .$test['TajukFail']."</font></td>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['JilidFail']. "</font></td>";
    echo"<td><font color='black'>". $test['StatusFail']. "</font></td>";    
    echo"<td> <a href ='daftarkemaskini.php?FailID=$id'>Edit</a>";
    echo"<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

but when I put it in there it doesnt work at all.

```
echo"<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');"><center>Delete</center></";>"
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes. Your code also had another syntax error at the end.

```
echo "<td> <a href='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick=\"return 
confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');\"><center>Delete</center></a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting javascript onclick code inside a double quote, which is being used to terminate the echo. Escape the double quotes:

```
echo"<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick=\"return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');\"><center>Delete</center></a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this--

```
echo "<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick=return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');><center>Delete</center></;>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the string:

```
echo "<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick=\"return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');\"><center>Delete</center></";>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please the change the line

```
 echo"<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');"><center>Delete</center></";>"
```

to

```
echo "<td> <a href ='padamfail.php?FailID=$id' onClick='return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??');' ><center>Delete</center></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="third">
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remve" name="<?php echo $row['choice_id']; ?>" onClick="deleteImage(<?php echo $row['choice_id']; ?>)"style="cursor:pointer;">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteImage(x){
var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this choice?");
if(conf == true){
window.location = "addnewentry/choiceRemove.php?id="+x;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo"<td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}' onclick='return confirm_alert(this);' >Delete</a></td>";`
**you should try this code ,it will definitely  work **

=

```js
<script>

//alert on delete

function confirm_alert(node) {

    return confirm("You are about to permanently delete a product. Click OK to continue or CANCEL to quit.");

}

</script>
```

```js
<script>

//alert on delete

function confirm_alert(node) {

    return confirm("You are about to permanently delete a product. Click OK to continue or CANCEL to quit.");

}

</script>
```

hoping this will help you